# Calculating an average from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I'm trying to get a monthly average figure from some spending data. I'm using d3.js to import and roll up the data from a csv, but I can't seem to filter out just the values from the resulting array before I go on to calculate the average spend.

I'm new to Javascript, and none of it feels at all intuitive.

```
// get filtered data (df)
d3.csv("/data/cic_data.csv", function (csv) {

// roll up and group data
var data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.date; })
    .rollup(function(d) { 
    return d3.sum(d, function(g) {return g.spend; });
    }).entries(csv);

var valueData = data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.values;
  })

var sum = 0;
for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
    sum += parseInt( data[i], 10 ); //don't forget to add the base
}

var avg = sum/data.length;

console.log(avg)
```

Here's a sample of my csv:

```
entity,level1,level2,supplier,type,date,spend,year,sin
BARKING DAGENHAM LONDON BOROUGH COUNCIL,Local Government,LONDON,GREEN SHOES ARTS COMMUNITY INTEREST COMPANY,LARGE,2014-07-01,4001.50,2014,12
BARKING DAGENHAM LONDON BOROUGH COUNCIL,Local Government,LONDON,GREENSPACE INFORMATION FOR GREATER LONDON CIC,OTHER,2014-07-01,2400.00,2014,12
BARKING DAGENHAM LONDON BOROUGH COUNCIL,Local Government,LONDON,GREEN SHOES ARTS COMMUNITY INTEREST COMPANY,LARGE,2014-06-01,8995.00,2014,12
BARKING DAGENHAM LONDON BOROUGH COUNCIL,Local Government,LONDON,GREEN SHOES ARTS COMMUNITY INTEREST COMPANY,LARGE,2014-05-01,640.00,2014,12
BARKING DAGENHAM LONDON BOROUGH COUNCIL,Local Government,LONDON,PUBLIC HEALTH ACTION SUPPORT TEAM CIC,SMALL,2014-05-01,6480.00,2014,12
BARKING DAGENHAM LONDON BOROUGH COUNCIL,Local Government,LONDON,GREEN SHOES ARTS COMMUNITY INTEREST COMPANY,LARGE,2014-04-01,7286.00,2014,12
BARKING DAGENHAM LONDON BOROUGH COUNCIL,Local Government,LONDON,GREEN SHOES ARTS COMMUNITY INTEREST COMPANY,LARGE,2014-03-01,15659.50,2014,12
BARKING DAGENHAM LONDON BOROUGH COUNCIL,Local Government,LONDON,THE SMALL BUSINESS CONSULTANCY LEICESTER CIC,OTHER,2014-03-01,6000.00,2014,12
BARKING DAGENHAM LONDON BOROUGH COUNCIL,Local Government,LONDON,GREEN SHOES ARTS COMMUNITY INTEREST COMPANY,LARGE,2014-02-01,4001.50,2014,12
```

Comment: I think the issue is that the second argument is an "accessor",  maybe you need to change it to the third argument which is a "callback".  Like try ```d3.csv("/data/cic_data.csv", function(d){ return d; }, function (csv) { ...```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want the average of all values in your csv?

After your nest:

```
var avg = d3.sum(data, function(d){
  return d.values; 
}) / data.length;
```

Or before:

```
var avg = d3.sum(csv, function(d){
  return +d.spend; 
}) / csv.length;
```

Or to avoid so much iterating, during your nest:

```
var sum = 0;
var data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
     return d.date;
   })
   .rollup(function(d) {
     return d3.sum(d, function(g) {
       sum += +g.spend;
       return g.spend;
     });
   }).entries(csv);

var avg = sum / data.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some comments on your code:

- If the code was complete as above some closing brackets are missing. Tip: use proper indentation to be aware of your scopes
- The variable valueDate doesn't do anything for you since you don't use it later. Also note, the filter function requires to return a boolean value to decide if an element if kept or dropped.
- Apart from the brackets your code doesn't work just because of you sum calculation. You need to access your daily values by using data[i].values not just data[i]

Note that after nesting your csv file you obtain an array like:
[{key: "2014-07-01", values: 6401.5}, {key: "2014-06-01", values: 8995},...]

Thus

```
data[0] = {key: "2014-07-01", values: 6401.5}
```

and

```
data[1] = {key: "2014-06-01", values: 8995}
```

That means your data array contains objects as elements. To access the values property you do

```
data[0].values
```

See also https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays.
Here is the complete code with some intermediate output to understand what happens to your data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // get filtered data (df)
  d3.csv("cic_data.csv", function (sv) {
    // roll up and group data
    console.log("Before nesting:");
    console.log(csv);
    var data = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.date; })
        .rollup(function(d) { 
          return d3.sum(d, function(g) {return g.spend; });
        }).entries(csv);
    console.log("After nesting:");
    console.log(data);

    var sum = 0;
    for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
        sum += parseInt( data[i].values, 10 ); //don't forget to add the base
    }

    var avg = sum/data.length;
    console.log(avg);
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ee2Dev, I only posted an excerpt of the script. I should have said. The date value is used later in the script for a chart.

Comment: woodbine: Ok, I see. My answer should still help, jusr change data[i] to data[i].values as I posted and it should work. It's cleaner to do coercion to a number with return +g.spend